# How to solve it ( EXC_BAD_ADDRESS in Objective-C )?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, thread-safety, crash-reports

sometimes, fatal error occurs in my app with EXC_BAD_ADDRESS error log.

What is the cause of my code?

## crash log

```
0. Crashed: GGMutableDictionary Isolation Queue
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x184e2c150 objc_msgSend + 16
1  CoreFoundation                 0x1862e0d04 -[NSDictionary descriptionWithLocale:indent:] + 916
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1862e0dac -[NSDictionary descriptionWithLocale:indent:] + 1084
3  Foundation                     0x186da35a4 _NSDescriptionWithLocaleFunc + 76
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1863788bc __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 8440
5  CoreFoundation                 0x18637678c _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 244
6  Foundation                     0x186da3418 +[NSString stringWithFormat:] + 68
7  app                            0x10019f4b8 -[TinyDB saveAsync] + 4296963256
8  app                            0x10019c86c __26-[TinyDB putString:value:]_block_invoke + 4296951916
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x18526e9a0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x18527bee0 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 84
11 app                            0x10019c7e0 -[TinyDB putString:value:] + 4296951776
```

## source file

This class is used asynchronously from many other class. 
This class should have thread safe. But EXC_BAD_ADDRESS fatal error occurs in saveAsync method. 
I think *weakDictionaryRef or isolationQueue* variables are deallocated. I want to fix this problem. What should I fix in this code? 
Thank you for your advice.

## TinyDB.h file

```
@interface TinyDB : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * docPath;
// @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary * dictionary;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFileManager * fileManager;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * dir;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL flagWrite;
- (instancetype)initWithFile:(NSString *)file;
- (NSString *)getDocPath;
- (void)putDouble:(NSString *)key value:(double)value;
- (void)putInt:(NSString *)key value:(NSInteger)value;
- (void)putMutableArray:(NSString *)key value:(NSMutableArray *)value;
- (void)putString:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value;
- (void)putTinyDB:(NSString *)key value:(TinyDB *)value;
- (void)putLong:(NSString *)key value:(NSInteger)value;
- (void)putBool:(NSString *)key value:(BOOL)value;
- (void)putDictionary:(NSString *)key value:(NSDictionary *)value;
- (id)get:(NSString *)key;
- (NSMutableArray *)getMutableArray:(NSString *)key;
- (BOOL)has:(NSString *)key;
- (void)saveAsync;
- (void)save;
- (NSString *)jsonString;
- (NSString *)stringify:(id)obj;
- (NSString *)getSet:(id)value;
- (NSString *)getPairSet:(NSString *)key value:(id)value;
- (NSMutableDictionary*)getMutableDictionary:(NSString*)key;
- (NSString *)getString:(NSString *)key;
- (BOOL)getBool:(NSString*)key;
- (NSArray *)allKeys;
- (void)removeObjectForKey:(NSString*)key;
@end
```

## TinyDB.m  file

```
@implementation TinyDB
{
@private dispatch_queue_t isolationQueue_;
@private __strong NSMutableDictionary * _myDictionary;
}
@synthesize docPath=docPath,fileManager=fileManager,dir=dir,flagWrite=flagWrite;
BOOL flagOnSave = false;
BOOL flagWrite = true;
NSString* dir;
NSString* docPath = @"";
NSLock* _dicLock=nil;
NSFileManager* fileManager;
__weak id _weakDictionaryRef;

-(id)initWithFile:(NSString *)file{
    self = [super init];
    docPath = file;
    // ##########################################
     isolationQueue_ = dispatch_queue_create([@"GGMutableDictionary Isolation Queue" UTF8String], DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    // ##########################################
    fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    dir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, true) firstObject];
    dir = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/myapp/",dir];
    BOOL flagFileExist = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@.myapp",dir,docPath]];
    _myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    if(flagFileExist){
        [BSDebugger log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DEBUG_myapp_CONFIG : File Found!!! %@ --> ",file]];
        @try{
            NSMutableDictionary* dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@.myapp",dir,docPath]];
            _myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dic];
        }@catch(NSException * e){
            _myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        }@finally{
        }
    }else{
        [BSDebugger log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DEBUG_myapp_CONFIG : File Not Found!!!--> %@ ",file]];
        _myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    _weakDictionaryRef = _myDictionary;
    [self saveAsync];
    return self;
}
-(void)putString:(NSString*)key value:(NSString*)value{
    dispatch_barrier_sync(isolationQueue_, ^{
        if(value == nil){
            return;
        }
        @try{
            [_myDictionary setObject:value forKey:key];
        }@catch(NSException* e){
            NSMutableDictionary* buff = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:_myDictionary];
            _myDictionary = buff;
            _weakDictionaryRef = _myDictionary;
            dispatch_barrier_sync(isolationQueue_, ^{
                [_myDictionary setObject:value forKey:key];
            });
        }@finally{
        }
        [self saveAsync];
    });
}

- (void)putDouble:(NSString *)key value:(double)value{
    dispatch_barrier_sync(isolationQueue_, ^{
        [_myDictionary setObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:value] forKey:key];
        [self saveAsync];
    });
}
- (void)putInt:(NSString *)key value:(NSInteger)value{
    dispatch_barrier_sync(isolationQueue_, ^{
        @try{
            [_myDictionary setObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:value] forKey:key];
        }@catch(NSException* e){
            NSMutableDictionary* buff = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:_myDictionary];
            _myDictionary = buff;
            _weakDictionaryRef = _myDictionary;
            [_myDictionary setObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:value] forKey:key];
        }@finally{
        }
        [self saveAsync];
    });
}
- (void)putMutableArray:(NSString *)key value:(NSMutableArray *)value{
    dispatch_barrier_sync(isolationQueue_, ^{
        if( key != nil && value != nil ){
            [_myDictionary setObject:value forKey:key];
            [self saveAsync];
        }
    });
}
- (void)putTinyDB:(NSString *)key value:(TinyDB *)value{
    dispatch_barrier_sync(isolationQueue_, ^{
        TinyDB* db = value;
        NSString* docuPath = [db getDocPath];
        @try{
            [_myDictionary setObject:docuPath forKey:key];
        }@catch(NSException* e){
            NSMutableDictionary* buff = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:_myDictionary];
            _myDictionary = buff;
            _weakDictionaryRef = _myDictionary;
            dispatch_barrier_sync(isolationQueue_, ^{
                [_myDictionary setObject:docuPath forKey:key];
            });
        }@finally{

        }
        [self saveAsync];
    });
}
- (void)putLong:(NSString *)key value:(NSInteger)value{
    dispatch_barrier_sync(isolationQueue_, ^{
        [_myDictionary setObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:value] forKey:key];
        [self saveAsync];
    });
}
- (void)putBool:(NSString *)key value:(BOOL)value{
    dispatch_barrier_sync(isolationQueue_, ^{
        [_myDictionary setObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:value] forKey:key];
        [self saveAsync];
    });
}
- (void)putDictionary:(NSString *)key value:(NSDictionary *)value{
    dispatch_barrier_sync(isolationQueue_, ^{
        [_myDictionary setObject:value forKey:key];
        [self saveAsync];
    });
}
-(void)removeObjectForKey:(NSString*)key{
    dispatch_barrier_sync(isolationQueue_, ^{
        if( _myDictionary != nil && [_myDictionary objectForKey:key] != nil ){
            [_myDictionary removeObjectForKey:key];
        }
    });
}
-(void) save{
    dispatch_barrier_sync(isolationQueue_, ^{
        @try {
            // NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"writeToFile Error : orgPath = %@/%@.myapp / %@",dir,docPath, self.dictionary ]);
            // NSMutableDictionary* nsDic = self.dictionary;
            if( _myDictionary != nil ){
                NSDictionary * _dictionary =
                (__bridge NSDictionary *)(CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                       (__bridge CFPropertyListRef)(_myDictionary),
                                                                       kCFPropertyListImmutable));
                if( _dictionary != nil ){
                    [_dictionary writeToFile:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@.myapp",dir,docPath]  atomically: false];
                }
            }
        }@catch (NSException *exception) {
            _myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:_myDictionary];
            _weakDictionaryRef = _myDictionary;
        }@finally {
        }
    });
}
// ################################################################
// normal function
- (NSString *)jsonString{
    __block NSString* buff = @"";
    dispatch_barrier_sync(isolationQueue_, ^{
        if( _myDictionary != nil ){
            NSDictionary * _dictionary = nil;
            // dispatch_barrier_sync(isolationQueue_, ^{
            _dictionary = (__bridge NSDictionary *)(CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                 (__bridge CFPropertyListRef)(_myDictionary),
                                                                                 kCFPropertyListImmutable));
            if( _dictionary != nil ){
                buff = [self stringify:_dictionary];
            }
        }else{
            NSLog(@"buff = [self stringify:_myDictionary]; is nil ");
        }

    });
    return buff;
}
- (NSString *)stringify:(id)obj{
    if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
        int idx = 0;
        NSString* buff = @"{";
        if( obj != nil ){
            NSDictionary* dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:obj]; //obj;
            for(NSString* key in dic){
                id value = [dic objectForKey:key];
                if(idx != 0){
                    buff = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@",buff,@","];
                }
                buff = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@",buff,[self getPairSet:key value:value]];
                idx++;
            }
        }
        buff = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@",buff,@"}"];
        return buff;
    }else if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
        int idx = 0;
        NSString* buff = @"[";
        if( obj != nil ){
            NSMutableArray* _a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for( int ai = 0; ai < [obj count]; ai++){
                if( [obj objectAtIndex:ai] != nil ){
                    [_a addObject:[obj objectAtIndex:ai]];
                }
            }
            NSArray* arr = [NSArray arrayWithArray:_a]; //obj;
            for(id value in arr){
                if(idx != 0){
                    buff = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@",buff,@","];
                }
                buff = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@",buff,[self getSet:value]];
                idx++;
            }
        }
        buff = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@",buff,@"]"];
        return buff;
    }else{
        return [self getSet:obj];
    }
}
- (NSString *)getSet:(id)value{
    NSString* buff = @"";
    if([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
        buff = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@\"%@\"",buff,value];
    }else if([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]){
        NSNumber* val = value;
        buff = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@",buff,[val stringValue]];
    }else{
        buff = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@",buff,[self stringify:value]];
    }
    return buff;
}
- (NSString *)getPairSet:(NSString *)key value:(id)value{
    NSString* buff = @"";
    if([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
        buff = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@\"%@\":\"%@\"",buff,key,value];
    }else if([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]){
        buff = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@\"%@\":%@",buff,key,[value stringValue]];
    }else{
        buff = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@\"%@\":%@",buff,key,[self stringify:value]];
    }
    return buff;
}
-(NSMutableDictionary*)getMutableDictionary:(NSString*)key{
    NSMutableDictionary* dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    id obj = [_myDictionary objectForKey:key];
    if(obj != nil){
        dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:obj];
    }
    return dic;
}
-(NSArray *)allKeys{
    __block NSArray* arr = nil;
    dispatch_barrier_sync(isolationQueue_, ^{
        if( _myDictionary != nil ){
            arr = [_myDictionary allKeys];
        }
    });
    return arr;
}
- (NSString *)getDocPath{
    return docPath;
}
- (id)get:(NSString *)key{
    __block id _obj = nil;
    dispatch_barrier_sync(isolationQueue_, ^{
        _obj = [_myDictionary objectForKey:key];
    });
    return _obj;
}
- (NSString *)getString:(NSString *)key{
    __block NSString* returnStr = @"";
    dispatch_barrier_sync(isolationQueue_, ^{
        if([_myDictionary objectForKey:key]==nil){
            returnStr = @"";
        }
        if([[_myDictionary objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
            returnStr = [_myDictionary objectForKey:key];
        }else{
            returnStr = @"";
        }
    });
    return returnStr;
}
- (BOOL)getBool:(NSString*)key{
    __block BOOL flag = false;
    dispatch_barrier_sync(isolationQueue_, ^{
        if([_myDictionary objectForKey:key]==nil){
            flag = NO;
        }
        if([[_myDictionary objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]){
            NSNumber* boolValue = [_myDictionary objectForKey:key];
            if([boolValue boolValue] == YES){
                flag = YES;
            }else{
                flag = NO;
            }
        }else{
            flag = NO;
        }
    });
    return flag;
}
- (NSMutableArray *)getMutableArray:(NSString *)key{
    __block NSMutableArray* _arr = nil;
    dispatch_barrier_sync(isolationQueue_, ^{
        _arr =  [_myDictionary objectForKey:key];
    });
    return _arr;
}
- (BOOL)has:(NSString *)key{
    __block BOOL flag = false;
    dispatch_barrier_sync(isolationQueue_, ^{
        if([_myDictionary objectForKey:key] != nil){
            flag = true;
        }else{
            flag = false;
        }
    });
    return flag;
}
// #########################
// save function
int flagTest = 0;
bool mark = 0;
NSTimer* saveTimer = nil;
-(void)saveAsync{ 
    @try { 
        [BSDebugger log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_weakDictionaryRef : %@ ",_weakDictionaryRef ]];
        if( _myDictionary != nil ){
            if( _weakDictionaryRef != nil ){
                NSDictionary * _dictionary = nil;
                _dictionary = (__bridge NSDictionary *)(CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                     (__bridge CFPropertyListRef)(_myDictionary),
                                                                                     kCFPropertyListImmutable));
                @try{
                    flagOnSave = true;
                    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier taskID = [myappCore beginBackgroundUpdateTask];
                    flagWrite = false;
                    NSString* orgPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@.myapp",dir,docPath ];
                    @try {  
                        if( _dictionary != nil ){
                            [_dictionary writeToFile:orgPath atomically:YES];
                        }
                    }@catch (NSException *exception) {
                        [BSDebugger log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DEBUG_myapp_TINYDB : %@",[exception callStackSymbols]]];
                    }@finally {
                    }
                    flagWrite = true;
                    flagOnSave = false;
                    [myappCore endBackgroundUpdateTask:taskID];
                }@catch (NSException *exceptionMain) {
                    [BSDebugger log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DEBUG_myapp_TINYDB : %@",[exceptionMain callStackSymbols]]];
                }@finally {
                    _dictionary = nil;
                }
                return;
                // });
            }
        }
    }@catch (NSException *exception) {
    }@finally {
        // [_dicLock unlock];
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas:

Turn on zombies ([How to enable NSZombie in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode)). You'll get more information about the object causing the crash when you do that.

If you can make the error happen at will, set a breakpoint at the top of `saveAsync` and step through it.

Change the `stringWithFormat` calls somehow so they don't reference anything that might be deallocated and see if the problem goes away. If it does, you'll know what was causing it.

I find it sometimes helps to override `retain` and `release` in objects I'm suspicious of and either print something out or set a breakpoint so I can see who might be over-releasing an object.